# Iterate JSON in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I have been trying to loop my JSON value to get the `data` output.I'm able to loop through `{GET_PUT_AWAY_Inspection_F:{.....}}`. If I try `(this.myData.GET_PUT_AWAY_Inspection.data)`, it's throwing me an error undefined. Any fixes?

```
 const putAwayPurchaseOrderList = putAwayPurchaseOrderListData.outBinds.GET_PUT_AWAY_Inspection_F;
        console.log(putAwayPurchaseOrderList)
        if (typeof putAwayPurchaseOrderList !== 'object') {
          this.myData = JSON.parse(putAwayPurchaseOrderList);
          console.log(this.myData);
         }
```

JSON

```
{
    "outBinds": {
        "GET_PUT_AWAY_Inspection_F": "{\"GET_PUT_AWAY_Inspection:\":{\"metadata\":[{\"name\":\"TRANSACTION_ID\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"PO_HEADER_ID\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"PO_NUMBER\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"PO_TYPE\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"VENDOR_NAME\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"VENDOR_SITE\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"CONTRACT\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"PO_LINE_ID\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"LINE_NUM\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"PO_LINE_LOCATION_ID\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"SHIPMENT_NUM\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"RECEIPT_NUM\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"PO_RELEASE_ID\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"RELEASE_NUM\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"ITEM\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"ITEM_ID\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"DESCRIPTION\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"SHELF_LIFE\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"DEFAULT_SUBINVENTORY\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"DEFAULT_LOCATOR\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"QUANTITY_ORDERED\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"RECEIPT_QUANTITY\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"UOM\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"DELIVERY_DATE\",\"type\":\"date\"},{\"name\":\"ROUTING_NAME\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"CURRENT_LOCATION\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"DESTINATION_TYPE\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"CATEGORY\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"RECEIPT_SOURCE_CODE\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"REQUESTOR\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"TRANSACTION_TYPE\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"LAST_UPDATE_DATE\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"ATTRIBUTE1\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"ATTRIBUTE2\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"ATTRIBUTE3\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"ATTRIBUTE4\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"ATTRIBUTE5\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"ATTRIBUTE6\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"RECEIPT_DATE\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"DATA_RECORD_FLAG\",\"type\":\"text\"}],\"data\": [ \n                                                 {\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_ID\":\"4994933\",\n                                                 \"PO_HEADER_ID\":\"190340\",\n                                                 \"PO_NUMBER\":\"3377\",\n                                                 \"PO_TYPE\":\"STD PO\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_NAME\":\"Agile Electronics Supplies\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_SITE\":\"AES_DALLAS\",\n                                                 \"PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID\":\"355938\",\n                                                 \"CONTRACT\":\"NA\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_ID\":\"257301\",\n                                                 \"LINE_NUM\":\"3\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_LOCATION_ID\":\"350469\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_NUM\":\"1\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID\":\"4909230\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_NUM\":\"1421\",\n                                                 \"PO_RELEASE_ID\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RELEASE_NUM\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ITEM\":\"AS10002348\",\n                                                 \"ITEM_ID\":\"210958\",\n                                                 \"DESCRIPTION\":\"RCA Connector\",\n                                                 \"SHELF_LIFE\":\"0\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_SUBINVENTORY\":\"012\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_LOCATOR\":\"\",\n                                                 \"QUANTITY_ORDERED\":\"4\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_QUANTITY\":\"1\",\n                                                 \"UOM\":\"Each\",\n                                                 \"DELIVERY_DATE\":\"22-MAR-20\",\n                                                 \"ROUTING_NAME\":\"Inspection Required\",\n                                                 \"CURRENT_LOCATION\":\"Dallas\",\n                                                 \"DESTINATION_TYPE\":\"Inventory\",\n                                                 \"CATEGORY\":\"MISC.MISC\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_SOURCE_CODE\":\"VENDOR\",\n                                                 \"REQUESTOR\":\"John, Mr. Smith\",\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_TYPE\":\"ACCEPT\",\n                                                 \"LAST_UPDATE_DATE\":\"13-03-2020 10:49:22\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE1\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE2\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE3\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE4\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE5\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE6\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_DATE\":\"13-03-2020 10:49:13\",\n                                                 \"DATA_RECORD_FLAG\":\"\"\n                                                 } ,\n                                                 {\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_ID\":\"4994920\",\n                                                 \"PO_HEADER_ID\":\"190318\",\n                                                 \"PO_NUMBER\":\"3355\",\n                                                 \"PO_TYPE\":\"STD PO\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_NAME\":\"Agile Electronics Supplies\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_SITE\":\"AES_DALLAS\",\n                                                 \"PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID\":\"355895\",\n                                                 \"CONTRACT\":\"NA\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_ID\":\"257266\",\n                                                 \"LINE_NUM\":\"1\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_LOCATION_ID\":\"350426\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_NUM\":\"1\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID\":\"4909223\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_NUM\":\"1414\",\n                                                 \"PO_RELEASE_ID\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RELEASE_NUM\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ITEM\":\"AS10002345\",\n                                                 \"ITEM_ID\":\"208955\",\n                                                 \"DESCRIPTION\":\"CMOS Battery\",\n                                                 \"SHELF_LIFE\":\"0\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_SUBINVENTORY\":\"\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_LOCATOR\":\"\",\n                                                 \"QUANTITY_ORDERED\":\"10\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_QUANTITY\":\"1\",\n                                                 \"UOM\":\"Each\",\n                                                 \"DELIVERY_DATE\":\"07-MAR-20\",\n                                                 \"ROUTING_NAME\":\"Inspection Required\",\n                                                 \"CURRENT_LOCATION\":\"Dallas\",\n                                                 \"DESTINATION_TYPE\":\"Inventory\",\n                                                 \"CATEGORY\":\"MISC.MISC\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_SOURCE_CODE\":\"VENDOR\",\n                                                 \"REQUESTOR\":\"John, Mr. Smith\",\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_TYPE\":\"ACCEPT\",\n                                                 \"LAST_UPDATE_DATE\":\"11-03-2020 07:53:33\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE1\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE2\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE3\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE4\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE5\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE6\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_DATE\":\"11-03-2020 07:53:08\",\n                                                 \"DATA_RECORD_FLAG\":\"\"\n                                                 } ,\n                                                 {\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_ID\":\"4994924\",\n                                                 \"PO_HEADER_ID\":\"190333\",\n                                                 \"PO_NUMBER\":\"3370\",\n                                                 \"PO_TYPE\":\"STD PO\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_NAME\":\"Agile Electronics Supplies\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_SITE\":\"AES_DALLAS\",\n                                                 \"PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID\":\"355922\",\n                                                 \"CONTRACT\":\"NA\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_ID\":\"257289\",\n                                                 \"LINE_NUM\":\"2\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_LOCATION_ID\":\"350453\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_NUM\":\"1\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID\":\"4909228\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_NUM\":\"1419\",\n                                                 \"PO_RELEASE_ID\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RELEASE_NUM\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ITEM\":\"AS10002346\",\n                                                 \"ITEM_ID\":\"210955\",\n                                                 \"DESCRIPTION\":\"HardDisk-150GB\",\n                                                 \"SHELF_LIFE\":\"0\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_SUBINVENTORY\":\"011\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_LOCATOR\":\"\",\n                                                 \"QUANTITY_ORDERED\":\"8\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_QUANTITY\":\"3\",\n                                                 \"UOM\":\"Each\",\n                                                 \"DELIVERY_DATE\":\"20-MAR-20\",\n                                                 \"ROUTING_NAME\":\"Standard Receipt\",\n                                                 \"CURRENT_LOCATION\":\"Dallas\",\n                                                 \"DESTINATION_TYPE\":\"Inventory\",\n                                                 \"CATEGORY\":\"MISC.MISC\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_SOURCE_CODE\":\"VENDOR\",\n                                                 \"REQUESTOR\":\"John, Mr. Smith\",\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_TYPE\":\"RECEIVE\",\n                                                 \"LAST_UPDATE_DATE\":\"12-03-2020 09:44:19\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE1\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE2\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE3\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE4\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE5\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE6\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_DATE\":\"12-03-2020 09:43:22\",\n                                                 \"DATA_RECORD_FLAG\":\"\"\n                                                 } ,\n                                                 {\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_ID\":\"4994940\",\n                                                 \"PO_HEADER_ID\":\"190344\",\n                                                 \"PO_NUMBER\":\"3381\",\n                                                 \"PO_TYPE\":\"STD PO\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_NAME\":\"Agile Electronics Supplies\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_SITE\":\"AES_DALLAS\",\n                                                 \"PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID\":\"355947\",\n                                                 \"CONTRACT\":\"NA\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_ID\":\"257308\",\n                                                 \"LINE_NUM\":\"2\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_LOCATION_ID\":\"350478\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_NUM\":\"1\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID\":\"4909233\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_NUM\":\"1424\",\n                                                 \"PO_RELEASE_ID\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RELEASE_NUM\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ITEM\":\"AS10002346\",\n                                                 \"ITEM_ID\":\"210955\",\n                                                 \"DESCRIPTION\":\"HardDisk-150GB\",\n                                                 \"SHELF_LIFE\":\"0\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_SUBINVENTORY\":\"\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_LOCATOR\":\"\",\n                                                 \"QUANTITY_ORDERED\":\"10\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_QUANTITY\":\"10\",\n                                                 \"UOM\":\"Each\",\n                                                 \"DELIVERY_DATE\":\"20-MAR-20\",\n                                                 \"ROUTING_NAME\":\"Standard Receipt\",\n                                                 \"CURRENT_LOCATION\":\"Dallas\",\n                                                 \"DESTINATION_TYPE\":\"Inventory\",\n                                                 \"CATEGORY\":\"MISC.MISC\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_SOURCE_CODE\":\"VENDOR\",\n                                                 \"REQUESTOR\":\"John, Mr. Smith\",\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_TYPE\":\"RECEIVE\",\n                                                 \"LAST_UPDATE_DATE\":\"16-03-2020 04:15:51\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE1\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE2\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE3\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE4\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE5\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE6\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_DATE\":\"16-03-2020 04:13:37\",\n                                                 \"DATA_RECORD_FLAG\":\"\"\n                                                 } ,\n                                                 {\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_ID\":\"4994923\",\n                                                 \"PO_HEADER_ID\":\"190330\",\n                                                 \"PO_NUMBER\":\"3367\",\n                                                 \"PO_TYPE\":\"STD PO\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_NAME\":\"Agile Electronics Supplies\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_SITE\":\"AES_DALLAS\",\n                                                 \"PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID\":\"355917\",\n                                                 \"CONTRACT\":\"NA\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_ID\":\"257285\",\n                                                 \"LINE_NUM\":\"2\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_LOCATION_ID\":\"350448\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_NUM\":\"1\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID\":\"4909227\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_NUM\":\"1418\",\n                                                 \"PO_RELEASE_ID\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RELEASE_NUM\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ITEM\":\"AS10002346\",\n                                                 \"ITEM_ID\":\"210955\",\n                                                 \"DESCRIPTION\":\"HardDisk-150GB\",\n                                                 \"SHELF_LIFE\":\"0\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_SUBINVENTORY\":\"\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_LOCATOR\":\"\",\n                                                 \"QUANTITY_ORDERED\":\"5\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_QUANTITY\":\"5\",\n                                                 \"UOM\":\"Each\",\n                                                 \"DELIVERY_DATE\":\"20-MAR-20\",\n                                                 \"ROUTING_NAME\":\"Standard Receipt\",\n                                                 \"CURRENT_LOCATION\":\"Dallas\",\n                                                 \"DESTINATION_TYPE\":\"Inventory\",\n                                                 \"CATEGORY\":\"MISC.MISC\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_SOURCE_CODE\":\"VENDOR\",\n                                                 \"REQUESTOR\":\"John, Mr. Smith\",\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_TYPE\":\"RECEIVE\",\n                                                 \"LAST_UPDATE_DATE\":\"11-03-2020 10:06:34\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE1\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE2\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE3\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE4\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE5\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE6\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_DATE\":\"11-03-2020 10:06:03\",\n                                                 \"DATA_RECORD_FLAG\":\"\"\n                                                 } ,\n                                                 {\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_ID\":\"4994919\",\n                                                 \"PO_HEADER_ID\":\"190323\",\n                                                 \"PO_NUMBER\":\"3360\",\n                                                 \"PO_TYPE\":\"STD PO\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_NAME\":\"Agile Electronics Supplies\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_SITE\":\"AES_DALLAS\",\n                                                 \"PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID\":\"355901\",\n                                                 \"CONTRACT\":\"3359\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_ID\":\"257270\",\n                                                 \"LINE_NUM\":\"1\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_LOCATION_ID\":\"350432\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_NUM\":\"1\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID\":\"4909225\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_NUM\":\"1416\",\n                                                 \"PO_RELEASE_ID\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RELEASE_NUM\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ITEM\":\"AL10004567\",\n                                                 \"ITEM_ID\":\"209955\",\n                                                 \"DESCRIPTION\":\"HardDisk-500GB\",\n                                                 \"SHELF_LIFE\":\"0\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_SUBINVENTORY\":\"010\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_LOCATOR\":\"\",\n                                                 \"QUANTITY_ORDERED\":\"2\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_QUANTITY\":\"1\",\n                                                 \"UOM\":\"Each\",\n                                                 \"DELIVERY_DATE\":\"09-MAR-20\",\n                                                 \"ROUTING_NAME\":\"Standard Receipt\",\n                                                 \"CURRENT_LOCATION\":\"Dallas\",\n                                                 \"DESTINATION_TYPE\":\"Inventory\",\n                                                 \"CATEGORY\":\"MISC.MISC\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_SOURCE_CODE\":\"VENDOR\",\n                                                 \"REQUESTOR\":\"John, Mr. Smith\",\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_TYPE\":\"RECEIVE\",\n                                                 \"LAST_UPDATE_DATE\":\"11-03-2020 07:46:33\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE1\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE2\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE3\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE4\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE5\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE6\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_DATE\":\"11-03-2020 07:45:11\",\n                                                 \"DATA_RECORD_FLAG\":\"\"\n                                                 } ,\n                                                 {\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_ID\":\"4994937\",\n                                                 \"PO_HEADER_ID\":\"190342\",\n                                                 \"PO_NUMBER\":\"3379\",\n                                                 \"PO_TYPE\":\"STD PO\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_NAME\":\"Agile Electronics Supplies\",\n                                                 \"VENDOR_SITE\":\"AES_DALLAS\",\n                                                 \"PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID\":\"355942\",\n                                                 \"CONTRACT\":\"NA\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_ID\":\"257305\",\n                                                 \"LINE_NUM\":\"2\",\n                                                 \"PO_LINE_LOCATION_ID\":\"350473\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_NUM\":\"1\",\n                                                 \"SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID\":\"4909232\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_NUM\":\"1423\",\n                                                 \"PO_RELEASE_ID\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RELEASE_NUM\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ITEM\":\"AS10002349\",\n                                                 \"ITEM_ID\":\"210959\",\n                                                 \"DESCRIPTION\":\"PCI Video Card\",\n                                                 \"SHELF_LIFE\":\"0\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_SUBINVENTORY\":\"\",\n                                                 \"DEFAULT_LOCATOR\":\"\",\n                                                 \"QUANTITY_ORDERED\":\"10\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_QUANTITY\":\"10\",\n                                                 \"UOM\":\"Each\",\n                                                 \"DELIVERY_DATE\":\"27-MAR-20\",\n                                                 \"ROUTING_NAME\":\"Standard Receipt\",\n                                                 \"CURRENT_LOCATION\":\"Dallas\",\n                                                 \"DESTINATION_TYPE\":\"Inventory\",\n                                                 \"CATEGORY\":\"MISC.MISC\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_SOURCE_CODE\":\"VENDOR\",\n                                                 \"REQUESTOR\":\"John, Mr. Smith\",\n                                                 \"TRANSACTION_TYPE\":\"RECEIVE\",\n                                                 \"LAST_UPDATE_DATE\":\"14-03-2020 07:25:06\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE1\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE2\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE3\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE4\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE5\":\"\",\n                                                 \"ATTRIBUTE6\":\"\",\n                                                 \"RECEIPT_DATE\":\"14-03-2020 07:23:48\",\n                                                 \"DATA_RECORD_FLAG\":\"\"\n                                                 } \n                                               ]}}"
    }
}
```

Comment: you have your data in "this.myData.GET_PUT_AWAY_Inspection.data"

Comment: @MustafaKunwa That didn't work through. I have tried that too. My bad. Sorry editing the question to `this.myData.GET_PUT_AWAY_Inspection.data`

Comment: I took JSON and tried it worked data is array of 7

Comment: Let me check it again

Comment: @MustafaKunwa Can you post your solution. I have tried it and still I'm getting the result as undefined

Comment: I just copy-paste your JSON that's it

Comment: @MustafaKunwa My bad there was colon which I was missing `GET_PUT_AWAY_Inspection:`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly format your JSON body accordingly. Only a string should be wrapped in "" (quotes). If it is an object don't wrap it in quotes. i.e

Instead of this:

```
"GET_PUT_AWAY_Inspection_F": "{\"GET_PUT_AWAY_Inspection:\":{\"metadata\":[{\"name\":\"TRANSACTION_ID\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"PO_HEADER_ID\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"PO_NUMBER\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"PO_TYPE\",\"type\":\"text\"}...]}"
```

Do this:

```
"GET_PUT_AWAY_Inspection_F": {\"GET_PUT_AWAY_Inspection:\":{\"metadata\":[{\"name\":\"TRANSACTION_ID\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"PO_HEADER_ID\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"name\":\"PO_NUMBER\",\"type\":\"text\"},{\"name\":\"PO_TYPE\",\"type\":\"text\"}...]}
```

Comment: The JSON which I have posted was valid. You can check that in any validator. You need to parse that first. The point where I went wrong was debugging. There were two colons  for `GET_PUY_AWAY_Inspection`. So the solution will be `this.myData['GET_PUT_AWAY_Inspection:'].data`